# Regular expression for strip out numbers which does not have any alphabets in middle

Tags: c#, regex

I want to strip out continues number string using regex from a text field minimum 9 digits long. It should not have any alphabets between the digits however space is allowed

for example

```
ABCD 123456789 -> 123456789
123M4567 -> blank
1234567890 ABCD -> 1234567890
123 456 789 ABCD -> 123456789 or 123 456 789 will also be fine
```

Comment: If the text field contains a char you want to return blank/an empty string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this...

```
/(\d{9,})|([\d\s]{11,})/
```

Comment: why did you put / to begining and end ?

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG - in some languages (like javascript, but unlike C#), regexes have special delimiters -  that `/`.